# Need help with rotating sword around player (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I'm having an issue with rotating an object around another object in my top-down roguelike in Unity 2D. My goal is to rotate a sword around a player based on joystick input from a controller (as shown in this image).
[image: Crappy image, circle within larger circle represents the joystick position.]

I have looked around online for any answers, but nothing has helped. All I have so far that is remotely close to what I want is code that keeps the sword attached to the box even when the box moves.

```
void Update()
{ 
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1.5f, 0);   
}
```

It might be necessary to note that the sword object is a child of the box object. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example:

```
public class SwordPointer : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float distance = 1;
    [SerializeField] private Transform sword;

    private void Update() {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //convert the input into an angle in radians, and convert that into degrees
        float rads = Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
        float degrees = rads * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        //use trig to position sword
        sword.localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(rads) * distance, 0, Mathf.Sin(rads) * distance); 
        //rotate to face away from center. note that the angle atan gives us is
        //oriented differently than unity's rotation, so we have to reverse it 
        //and add 90.
        sword.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -degrees + 90, 0);
    }
}
```

This uses simple trig to position the sword according to the player input. We convert the input into an angle and apply that angle to the sword's *local* position and rotation. You would make the sword a child of the hero.

This is using the default horizontal and vertical axes to aim the sword, but you are probably actually using those axes for movement, in which case you'll need separate axes for the sword.

This example code positions the sword relative to its parent; this means that if the hero turns, the sword orientation will change. E.g. if the hero is facing to the right, pressing up on the sword controls will actually point the sword to the right. If the hero can turn, you'll probably need to make some tweaks so that the sword orientation remains relative to the screen instead of the hero.

Comment: how would I go about implementing separate axes for the sword?

Comment: never mind, i figured out what you are talking about. I'm not stupid, just sometimes my brain lags like an old modem.

Comment: @GusK Please research Unity's Input and learn how to define axes: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html
You should also consider using the new input system, which may be a bit more confusing to set up but is much more sophisticated: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html

Comment: @Gusk Please mark up Kevin's answer if it helped you. That is what the voting system is for.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak a few things from @Kevin 's contribution to change rotation axes, but this is what I ended up with! Many thanks to @Kevin for providing 99% of the framework I needed!

```
[SerializeField] private float distance = 1;
[SerializeField] private Transform sword;

public void Update()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("ControllerAimX");
    float y = -Input.GetAxis("ControllerAimY");

    //convert the input into an angle in radians, and convert that into degrees
    float rads = Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
    float degrees = rads * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    //use trig to position sword
    sword.localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(rads) * distance, Mathf.Sin(rads) * distance, 0);
    //rotate to face away from center. note that the angle atan gives us is
    //oriented differently than unity's rotation, so we have to reverse it 
    //and add 90.
    sword.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, degrees - 90); }
```